# Approximating density of hydrogen in [observable] universe

Tags: cosmology, redshift, density, hubble-constant

Let universe be completely made from hydrogen. And also we have redshift $z= 6$. with Hubble constant $H_{0} = 2.1941747572815535\times 10^{-18}\:\mathrm{s}^{-1}$. We also know that density of the universe $\rho =\frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$ ($G= 6.67\times 10^{-11}\:\mathrm{m^3\ kg^{-1}\ s^{-2}}$).

**Is the following approach right to find the number density of hydrogen in universe?**

First we calculate density $\rho =\frac{3H^2}{8\pi G}$, then we have
$1+z = \sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}$. From that we get $v = H\times R$ and from this we calculate $R$, the radius of observable universe. With that, we calculate volume of universe $V = (4\pi/3)R^3$ and we get Mass $M=\rho V$. Then we calculate number of Hydrogen atoms with $N = M/m_{\mathrm{hydrogen}}$. Now we have number density of hydrogen $\rho = N/V$.

Is this solution right? Or we must solve it another way?

<sub>The source of question is National Olympiad of Iran which is not available in English so the above is my translation for the question.</sub>

Comment: H to 16 significant figures? LOL.

Comment: @RobJeffries It is calculated by changing the non-SI usual unit KM/sMpc to SI units. I know we don't know the hubble constant with this accuracy and the number is made by changing H= 67.8 KM/sMpc. Parsec in the denominator caused this!

Comment: @RobJeffries Sorry, It was H0 in the main question. I forgot the index. Also, I Know we don't gain precision by doing a unit conversion, We use H and in the formula and at the last part, we substitute it by an appropriate approx, like 2.2.

Comment: I think there some rules about check-my-homework questions, but here are some hints: Your definition of redshift is the Doppler shift, while you need the cosmological definition 1+z = 1/a; your definition of the Hubble law confuses radius with distance; and you don't need to care about the volume if you're only interested in the density.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It seems to be a maths question, not about real world astronomy

Comment: There are Doppler's shift, Hubble's law, universe density. I think that is astro?

Answer (score 1):

So to estimate the answer, you need to convert the mass density to number density by $n_H = \rho_H / m_H$. After getting the current number density you need to redshift it to finite $z$, here $z=6$. Keep in mind the density of hydrogen evolves $\sim (1+z)^3$ due to the expansion of the universe.

That said, the assumption 'let universe be completely made from hydrogen' renders this question highly unrealistic, hence I agree with @James K that this is not real world astronomy. In the real world, only about 5% of the total energy is made of baryons, among which Hydrogen abundance is $\sim 75\%$. Also, at redshift $z\sim 6$, star formation etc. lowers the neutral hydrogen gas density, c.f. recent observations [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02037.pdf) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.05553.pdf).